# How return x character of a string WITHOUT *

Tags: python, string, return, character

my question , Define a function generate_n_chars() that takes an integer n and a character c and returns a string, n characters long, consisting only of c:s. For example, generate_n_chars(5,"x") should return the string "xxxxx". (Python is unusual in that you can actually write an expression 5 * "x" that will evaluate to "xxxxx". For the sake of the exercise you should ignore that the problem can be solved in this manner.) .
My code:

```
def generate_n_chars(c, n):
      d = ""
      c = raw_input("Give a character: ")
      n = raw_input("Give a word: ")
      for i in n:
          if i not in c:
             d += i
      return d    

print ("You word have " + str(generate_n_chars('c', 'n') + " character"))
```

so, when I write hallo a come only a x , and I will five , because hallo have five words.I will to come xxxxx but WITHOUT '5 * x' .Very Thanks for yours help!

Comment: your `n` is not integer.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer , and how to do?

Comment: you run `generate_n_chars('c', 'n')` so you send string `"c"` and string `"n"` but you should use variables `c` and `n` - `generate_n_chars(c, n)`. And use `raw_input()` outside `generate_n_chars`

Comment: Iterate n times using  `range(n)` and concatenate the string to new (initially empty) string

Comment: @ Moinuddin Quadri , how to do?

Comment: your code does something different than you have in description. It counts char `c` in text `n`

Comment: Your posted code doesn't do anything close to the assigned task, and it looks like you lack a basic understanding of fundamental concepts like function parameters.

Comment: @furas can you please explain me , maybe I have the question false Understand , my English knowledge is a little poor .. Thanks

Comment: in description you have `"takes an integer n"` but in code you ask `"n = raw_input("Give a word: ")` - so you have to ask for number but you ask for word.

Comment: you have to do `return the string "xxxxx"` but you print `"You word have ... character"` - so it all makes no sense.

Comment: @furas now Understand... in n i should a integer to write , not a word...thanks

Comment: @furas , the question as i Understand , I now , I have false Understand...but was i think that I should to write a word and than this word return as string character ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking you to create a function(`def`) named `generate_n_chars()` that takes an integer(`int`) value,`n` and character(`char`) value,`c` as parameters. Here, `c` is any character input by user,lets say user inputs `x` and `n` is how many times the character(`c`) should be printed so lets say user wants it to print 5 times and therefore inputs `5`. Then the result would be `xxxxx`. 5 x's.

```
def generate_n_chars(n, c):
        result = ""
        for i in range(n):
            result += c
        return result

    inputChar = input("Enter the character:")
    inputNum = int(input("Enter the number of times " + str(inputChar) + " to be printed:"))
    print("Result: " + str(generate_n_chars(inputNum, inputChar)))
```

Output:

```
Enter the character:x
Enter the number of times x to be printed:5
Result: xxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks , and two Time thanks because you answer me with gut word on my mistake.... my English knowledge is a little poor and I have to Understand that I should to write a word.... that was my mistake ....

Comment: No problem,I understood you were also having problem understanding, as English is not your native language. Upvote my answer to instead of thanking me ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can loop a while loop to count till n and break out once the number has been reached.

```
   def generate_n_chars(n , c):
        for i in range(len(c)):
            while i <= n:
                print(c[i])
                i+=1
            break

    def main():
        generate_n_chars(5,"this is")
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use function rjust....

```
"".rjust(10,"5")
```

In your example:

```
print ("You word have " + "".rjust(5, 'x') + " character")
```